# Lua/love2d: Method doesn't work because of string.sub

Tags: string, class, object, lua

I'm trying to make an interpreter based on the python code from [this](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part9/) tutorial. But I'm getting a strange error that looks like a bug, but I'm not totally sure. Here's what's going on.

(I'm also using the [classic](https://github.com/rxi/classic) library for oop. Maybe the error is there? idk)

```
function Lexer:advance()
    --Advance self.pos and set self.currentChar
    self.pos = self.pos + 1
    if self.pos > string.len(self.text) then
        self.currentChar = ""
    else
        --if self.pos == 30 then error(self:getNextToken()) end--Outputs 'Object'
        self.currentChar = string.sub(self.text, self.pos, self.pos)
        --if self.pos == 30 then error(self:getNextToken()) end--Outputs 'classic.lua:63: attempt to call method 'new' (a nil value)
    end
end
```

Notice how before and after string.sub the outputs are different. One outputs what it's supposed to output (an object) and the other outputs an error. It seems as though string.sub is causing this, but I have no idea why it would seeing that it doesn't do that before (notice I'm checking the 30th character, it goes through every character before).

Somebody also asked for the output so here it is:

```
Error

classic.lua:63: attempt to call method 'new' (a nil value)


Traceback

classic.lua:63: in function 'getNextToken'
parser.lua:16: in function 'eat'
parser.lua:156: in function 'factor'
parser.lua:123: in function 'term'
parser.lua:106: in function 'expr'
parser.lua:85: in function 'assignmentStatement'
parser.lua:72: in function 'statement'
parser.lua:48: in function 'statementList'
parser.lua:32: in function 'compoundStatement'
...
parser.lua:32: in function 'compoundStatement'
parser.lua:24: in function 'program'
parser.lua:170: in function 'parse'
interpreter.lua:62: in function 'interpret'
main.lua:19: in function 'load'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

The `...` is probably super annoying, but it doesn't have that much in it and it behaves how it should.

I don't know how necessary this is, but I'll also include the self:getNextToken() method for everyone who wants to check that.

```
function Lexer:getNextToken()
    --Tokenizer
    while self.currentChar ~= "" do
        
        if self.currentChar == " " or self.currentChar =="\n" then
            self:skipWhiteSpace()
            goto continue
            
        elseif (string.gsub(self.currentChar, "%a", "") == "") then
            return self:id()
            
        elseif tonumber(self.currentChar) ~= nil then
            return Token(int, self:integer())
            
        elseif self.currentChar == ":" and self:peek() == "=" then
            self:advance()
            self:advance()
            return Token(assign, ":=")
            
        elseif self.currentChar == ";" then
            self:advance()
            return token(semi, ";")
            
        elseif self.currentChar == "+" then
            self:advance()
            return Token(plus, "+")
        elseif self.currentChar == "-" then
            self:advance()
            return Token(minus, "-")
            
        elseif self.currentChar == "*" then
            self:advance()
            return Token(mul, "*")
        elseif self.currentChar == "/" then
            self:advance()
            return Token(div, "/")
            
        elseif self.currentChar == "(" then
            self:advance()
            return Token(lparen, "(")
        elseif self.currentChar == ")" then
            self:advance()
            return Token(rparen, ")")
            
        elseif self.currentChar == "." then
            self:advance()
            return Token(dot, ".")
            
        end
        
        self:error()
        
        ::continue::
    end
    return Token(eof, "none")
end
```

I have no idea what's going on, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the whole stack traceback

Comment: what's `an error` supposed to mean? why do you think the compiler tells you something like: error in file x, line y: attempt to index global z, a nil value?  why do you reduce that valid information to a useless `an error` when asking for help?` `a strange error that is looking like a bug` is also completely useless. the biggest problem beginners have is that they see the word error, then switch of their brains and run for help. all they needed to do is to stay, read and understand what the compiler is trying to tell them.

Comment: Egor Skriptunoff I edited in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Current char's getting through the stack of elseifs in `function Lexer:getNextToken()`

Put a `print('||' ..self.currentChar ..'||')` statement before `self:error()` then look for the char surrounded by pipes in your output.  You can concatenate any frame of your choosing, those just happen to be easy to read.

```
||a||
```

Decide if it's another char that needs an elseif defined there, or comment out the `self:error()` and see if your app proceeds, unhindered.

Comment: Doyousketch2 It's not the self:error() function that gives me problems. That makes the program stop if a character that doesn't work is detected, and that gives the error message 'invalid character: [char]'. The error message I'm getting is "classic.lua:63: attempt to call method 'new' (a nil value)"

Comment: k, I see that now that you included the traceback.  I thought you meant that the error was being propagated back from that point, and it made sense at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the problem, and jeez this is embarrassing.

`return token(semi, ';')` -> `return Token(semi, ';')`

Pro tip: make sure you don't make typos that make you look for hours.